# Ubuntu 17.04 Pointer Speed Broken

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 17.04, mouse-pointer

I tried everything to lower the pointer speed. Starting from the Settings Menu, ending up with the terminal commands. In terminal, after finding the ID of my mouse, and the ID of the Acceleration speed, it shows some kind of error after the execute of the command.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

**OS: Ubuntu 17.04 64bit**

**Mouse: SteelSeries Kana Gaming Mouse**

Comment: I can see that many of us have the same problem. I am kinda new to Ubuntu services, so my question may be stupid: - Will they release some update for the bugs we all encounter?

Comment: "some kind of error" is not an information. What exactly did you try and what was the problem?

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1683145 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1682193 for the bug on Launchpad.

Comment: Work-around [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1683145/comments/6)